# Git (GitFlow) Finish Release Error: Code.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, git-flow

I'm working through a simple GitFlow example.  When I get to the final step for finishing the release I get the error below.  Why is it looking for Code.exe?  Why does Visual Studio Code have anything to do with this process?  I closed all my instances of VSCode and ran `$ git flow release finish 2.2.124.0` from the Bash command-line and I still get this error.

```
$ git flow release finish 2.2.124.0
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' --wait: C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
Fatal: Tagging failed. Please run finish again to retry.
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what is going on now.  Recently VSCode switched to a user based install version instead of a system-wide install version.  When I installed Git I selected VSCode as my editor.  Then I uninstalled the system-wide VSCode version from my machine.  During the GitFlow finish release process it attempts to launch the editor you selected, which no longer exists cause I removed it.  So I uninstalled VSCode and Git, then re-installed them, now the process works.  I'm pretty sure I only needed to re-install Git but I did both.